# in Bash, how can I remove a numeric range of directories?

Tags: bash, directory, arguments, range, alias

I am writing an alias to remove a range of directories that contain integers.  I can't figure out how to replace the values e.g. 322 and 394 with 2 variables (arguments) that I add when entering the command.

This is the alias in its current state.

```
    alias rRange='ls -1 | awk -F'"'"'v'"'"' '"'"'{if ( ($2>=322) && ($2<=394) ) print "rm -fRv " $0 }'"'"''
```

but I would like to be able to enter:

```
    rRange 322 394
```

to be able to drive that alias instead. Currently those values are hard coded in there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### A step by step, bottom-up, deconstruction on how to solve this and many similar problems:

To generate an integer sequence, use bash brace-expansion (see details in `man bash`):

```
$ echo {2..5}
2 3 4 5
```

You may also generate non-consecutive and multiple ranges:

```
$ echo {2..4} {8..9}
2 3 4 8 9
```

If you have variables instead of constants, you can use `eval` to expand them:

```
$ a=2 b=5
$ eval echo {$a..$b}
2 3 4 5
```

To list any file/directory which contains these values, enclose with `*`s:

```
$ eval echo *{$a..$b}*
```

To remove the files instead of listing them, use `rm` instead of `echo`:

```
$ eval rm *{$a..$b}*
```

To remove directories use `rm -r` (if directories are non-empty) or `rmdir` (if-empty):

```
$ eval rm -r *{$a..$b}*
$ eval rmdir *{$a..$b}*
```

Comment: `eval echo {$a..$b}` is non-standard. Numeric brace expansion was never designed to have variables defining the range (or increment). Any time you are having to call `eval` on something other than an arithmetic or matching expression, double-check man bash.

Comment: Thanks David for the comment.  bash performs 7 expansions, brace-expansion is the 1st of the 7. eval adds another shell level. The eval coming before the echo happens to work because the evaluation order is left to right and when the `echo` on the brace-expansion is encountered, the variables have already been expanded to constants. It works, but I agree that this is borderline reliable territory.  Perhaps `eval "echo {$a..$b}"` would have made this clearer. Of course, the quoting would break the surrounded by asterisks case.

Comment: You are 100% correct..., and I think that is the exact reason that variables within brace expansion are not supported. Since brace expansion happens first, the expansion has no way of knowing what the values are. I am aware of that trick to **force it to work** but the only other place I've every seen it used is on the **Bash Hackers** site along with a warning that it isn't standard and that if you are considering it -- there is probably another supported way to accomplish what you are trying to do...

Answer (score 2):

Use a function instead of an alias:

```
function rRange {
    for (( I = $1; I <=$2; ++I )); do
        [[ -d $I ]] && rm -fRv "$I"
    done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More expansion.

```
rm ... *{322..394}*
```